# Im having an error in gradle, what should i do?

Tags: java, android, gradle

I want to put cardview in my project, and it needs to implement the dependency (based on what i watched)

i entered the dependency in the build.gradle that i searched, and synced...

But the gradle project failed to sync and this is the error:

```
build.gradle:29: Gradle DSL method not found: 'imeplementation()'
Possible causes:
The project 'Notifier' may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g. 'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0).
<a href="fixGradleElements">Upgrade plugin to version 3.5.0 and sync project</a>

The project 'Notifier' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
<a href="open.wrapper.file">Open Gradle wrapper file</a>

The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
<a href="apply.gradle.plugin">Apply Gradle plugin</a>
```

this is the build.gradle in app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.notifier"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    imeplementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply mistyped, `implementation` not `imeplementation` .